# FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a function (found in field id in document messages/jam5Xj1DryC4Xc)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

Я хочу создать новый документ в firestore firebase, но выводит ошибку

Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a function (found in field id in document messages/STvSdTnV5NUPz228zLQq)

form.js

```
    e.preventDefault()
    await messagesApi.sendMessage(message, date(), setMessage, id)
};

return(
        <form className="formSending" onSubmit={(e) => sendMessage(e)}>
            // code
        </form>
    )
```

api.js

````
    sendMessage: async (message, date, id) => {
        if(message){
            await db.collection('messages').add({
                message,
                id,
                date,
                key: new Date()
            })
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй не передавать "e" через анонимную функцию, а получи прямо в

```
sendMessage = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  ...
}
```